# Closure vs. function declaration in struct

Tags: rust, rust-actix

I'm having trouble (as a newbie) getting my application to compile. This is likely the most obvious detail but I'm struggling with comprehending what's happening.

I'm writing a wrapper struct for the Actix Web server library. My struct is defined as such:

```
struct CustomServer {
    connections: IncomingRequets,
    server: HttpServer<App, fn() -> App>,
    address: String,
    port: i32,
}
```

I'm attempting to create the struct and return it via a function:

```
let address: Handle<JsString> = cx.argument::<JsString>(0)?;
let port: Handle<JsNumber> = cx.argument::<JsNumber>(1)?;
let server = server::new(|| {
    App::new()
        .middleware(middleware::Logger::default())
        .default_resource(|r| r.f(index))
});
// Export the server struct
CustomServer {
    address: address.value(),
    port: port.value() as i32,
    server: server,
    connections: IncomingRequets {
        requests: HashMap::new(),
    },
}
```

`expected fn pointer, found closure`. I do understand that this is likely due to a missing piece in my understanding of how concrete structs and types are declared. I also understand that I'm passing in a closure as opposed to a function.

So my thought process is: a) how can I declare a closure as part of the `HttpServer` parameters or b) can I declare the function within the struct and return it as a factory/generator that returns the app?

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates, types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. Try to produce something that reproduces your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) or you can reproduce it in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) as well.

Comment: Applying the duplicates, you'll probably need to use `server: HttpServer<App, Box<Fn() -> App>>` with the corresponding change inside the method, but since there's no MCVE, it's hard to state what exactly you'll need.